# Pattern matching on Orderless functions inside Hold

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching

```
MatchQ[Hold[1 + 2], Hold[2 + 1]]
```

returns `False`. But in the presence of a `Blank[]` in the matching pattern as in the example below

```
MatchQ[Hold[1 + 2], Hold[2 + _]]
```

which returns `True`, apparently the fact that `Plus` is `Orderless` is being respected.

Apart from doing something like removing the `Orderless` attribute from `Plus`, how can I make the order matter when pattern-matching in a case like this? Where can I read more about this in the documentation?

Comment: Strongly related (the general case is explained): "[Pattern does not match with Orderless head](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94432/280)."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to prevent `Plus` being an active head in the pattern.  One natural method is `Block` to temporarily change all appearances of `Plus` as suggested by rcollyer:

```
Block[{Plus},
  MatchQ[Hold[1 + 2], Hold[2 + _]]
]
```

> False

For that matter you could use `With` as well, which replaces only explicit appearances:

```
With[{Plus = Null},
  MatchQ[Hold[1 + 2], Hold[2 + _]]
]
```

> False

**More directly** you can make the head of `[2, _]` a pattern so that `Plus` is not active:

```
MatchQ[Hold[1 + 2], Hold[(h : Plus)[2, _]]]
```

> False

`h` here is arbitrary.

Perhaps better is [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Verbatim.html):

```
MatchQ[Hold[1 + 2], Hold[Verbatim[Plus][2, _]]]
```

> False

Answer (score 7):

A quick and dirty solution to this would be to match the structure first, and the operator `Plus` afterwards:

```
MatchQ[Hold[1 + 2], Hold[f_[2, _]] /; f === Plus]
MatchQ[Hold[2 + 1], Hold[f_[2, _]] /; f === Plus]
```

(* {False,True} *)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of modifying the definition of such a basic function, change it temporarily. The following code

```
With[{Plus = tempPlus}, {MatchQ[Hold[1 + 2], Hold[2 + _]], MatchQ[Hold[1 + 2], Hold[1 + _]]}]
```

yields

```
{False, True}
```

Comment: A simpler, but related, method is to use `Block[{Plus}, MatchQ[...]]` as the attributes are temporarily stripped from `Plus` because of `Block`.

Comment: +1 Definitely better than modifying the definition of a basic function