# Using MatchQ (or other means) to parse an expression using sums of COS or SIN correctly

Tags: pattern-matching, parsing

I am writing a function that will take an expression as input. I want to make sure the expression is valid first before processing it. Looking for a correct to use `MatchQ` (or if you have better method) to use which will return `True` or `False` when given the expression.

### Specifications

The expression will have the following form

```
a1 Cos[x+b1] + a2 Cos[x+b2] + a3 Cos[x+b3] + ....
```

*OR*

```
a1 Sin[x+b1] + a2 Sin[x+b2] + a3 Sin[x+b3] + ....
```

So if you can parse one, then with some trick, can use the same parser with the other using `OR`.

There can one or more terms there. Also, the amplitudes (the $a_i$) can be there or not there. Also, there is no need to check what is used for argument to the trig functions. So if expression is `Cos[Cos[x]]` then that is ok, only FIRST level needs to be validated. The expression will be passed by `TrigReduce[]` before. Your parser only needs to check for the above top level form.

Hence the following are all valid expression and should return `True`

```
Sin[x]
a Sin[x]
a Sin[x] + Sin[x +b]
Sin[x] + Sin[x + b] + c Sin[x]
```

These are NOT valid:

```
Sin[x] + Cos[x]  (*mixed*)
a + Sin[x]  (*first term has no sin nor cos *)
Sin[x]+ b + Sin[x + v]
```

So the function needed will have this specification

```
parse[expr_]
```

and will return either `True` or `False`.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

### Test suite

To help you in making the parser, here are few expressions that should return `True` and another set that should return `False`

```
ClearAll[x, a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3];
trueTests = {
  3 Cos[x],
  a1 Cos[x + b1],
  Cos[x] + a1 Cos[x + b1],
  a1 Cos[x] + a1 Cos[x + b1] + a2 Cos[x + b2],
  3 Sin[x],
  a1 Sin[x + b1],
  Sin[x] + a1 Sin[x + b1],
  a1 Sin[x] + a1 Sin[x + b1] + a2 Sin[x + b2]
  }

falseTests = {
  a1,
  a1 Cos[x + b1] + Sin[x],
  Cos[x] + b1,
  a1 Cos[x] + a1 Cos[x + b1] + a2 Sin[x + b2],
  Cos[x] + Sin[x]
  }
```

Comment: Naming your head with repeated would be the way to go.

Something like `MatchQ[{2 Sin[x], 4 Sin[2 x], Cos[x]}, {(_. (h : (Sin | Cos))[_. x + _.]) ..}]` should work

Comment: @RiemannZeta Nice going.  I am working on an answer now that will use the same thing!  (and explain in more detail)

Comment: @RiemannZeta there's mythology about naming things, and one where giving something a name fixes its form. Spooky. :)

Comment: Nasser, congratulations on joining the 10,000 Club!  \*toot\*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how I would approach this problem.  First, when possible we should make use of the Attributes of the functions in use with regard to their effect on pattern matching.

These attributes follow the natural application of the functions to which they apply so often they make mathematical matching easier.  (Sometimes you [don't want that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30192/121).)

The [`OneIdentity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OneIdentity.html) attribute of `Times` lets this pattern match:

```
MatchQ[#, _. "X"] & /@ {"X", 5 "X"}
```

> {True, True}

`_.` is an [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) pattern (it uses the [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Default.html) value).

`Plus` in your application is somewhat more tricky because `Plus[x]` evaluates to `x` directly.  Since I don't know how to both prevent this invalid simplification and preserve the `OneIdentity` behavior illustrated above I will have to turn to a more manual approach and use [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html).  Here is my solution (`p2`):

```
p1 = (_. (h : Sin | Cos)[_]) ..;
p2 = p1 | Verbatim[Plus][p1];
```

Test:

```
MatchQ[#, p2] & /@ trueTests
MatchQ[#, p2] & /@ falseTests
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
>
> {False, False, False, False, False}

There are several parts to this pattern.  The first listed was explained preemptively by [RiemannZeta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346/riemannzeta) in a comment above.

- By *naming* the [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html) `Sin | Cos` we require *all* appearances (in any given matching application) of that pattern to be identical for the pattern to match.
- [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Repeated.html) is used to match one or more instances of a given pattern
- The [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) pattern `_.` is used in an implicit `Times`, as already illustrated
- [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html) is used to match either a raw instance of the pattern `p1` or multiple instances within `Plus`
- [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Verbatim.html) is used to prevent `Plus[p1]` from evaluating to `p1` which would then be a raw `Repeated` object.

Another way to write `p1` that might be easier to read is this:

```
p1 = (_. _Sin) .. | (_. _Cos) ..;
```

---

Responding to Leonid's answer, if one prefers not to use "tricks" such as the pattern behavior of functions with `OneIdentity` it adds very little code to do without that:

```
p0 = (h : Sin | Cos)[_];
p1 = (p0 | _*p0) ..;
p2 = p1 | Verbatim[Plus][p1];

MatchQ[#, p2] & /@ trueTests
MatchQ[#, p2] & /@ falseTests
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
>
> {False, False, False, False, False}

Worth noting is that here as well as above the pattern parts need not be assigned e.g. `p0`, `p1` if one prefers to build the pattern in one shot:

```
p = # | Verbatim[Plus][#] &[(# | _*#) ..] &[(h : Sin | Cos)[_]];

MatchQ[#, p] & /@ trueTests
MatchQ[#, p] & /@ falseTests
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
>
> {False, False, False, False, False}

Comment: Another variant, without Verbatim: `p2 = With[{p1 = (_. (h : Sin | Cos)[_]) ..},
  HoldPattern[p1 | Plus[p1]]]`

Comment: @Rolf Yes, that should work too.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a parser that seems to satisfy your specs (with an improvement from Mr.Wizard):

```
ClearAll[parse, sameQ, reduce];
parse[HoldPattern[Plus[terms__?parse]]] /; sameQ[terms] := True;
parse[(a_: 1) * (_Sin | _Cos)] := True;
parse[x_] := False;

sameQ[terms__] /; MemberQ[{terms}, _Times] := sameQ @@ reduce[{terms}];
sameQ[__Sin | __Cos] := True;
sameQ[__] := False;

SetAttributes[reduce, Listable];
reduce[Times[a_, x : (_Sin | _Cos)]] := x;
reduce[x_] := x;
```

It is less concise than one could have made it (compared to the answer of Mr.Wizard, for example), but it has an advantage to be completely straight-forward and also extensible, and is along the lines of how one might write parsers in general (use recursion). In general, pattern-matching is akin regexps (but on parsed expressions), and in many instances I've found recursion to be more powerful approach.

Comment: Leonid, since you are looking at this can you tell me if there is a way to use the `OneIdentity` attribute of `Plus` without having `Plus[p1]` (in my example) "simplify" to `p1`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If it exists, I don't see it at the moment. But, you know, for some time now I prefer simple things :).

Comment: Leonid would you please consider commenting your code?  There are parts of this I don't understand, or at least I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard But what do you find hard to understand in this code? To me, it looks completely self-explanatory, to the extent that comments might actually make it *less* clear / explicit (see my edit though, you might be referring to the previous version of the code).

Comment: You sound like me with ~infix~! "But it's so clear: you just read it left to right, like English!" :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Perhaps :) But I truly don't see how this could could have been much more explicit (I could have introduced a couple of additional named functions, but that wouldn't make it so much clearer to justify their presence, I think).

Comment: You already had a +1 from me, but the condition, `MemberQ[{terms}, _Times]` strikes me as particularly clever as it solves a common problem: how does one create a pattern where at least one argument must have a specific form? I hadn't thought of using `MemberQ` in that way.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks :). I have used this idiom for some time, by now. I agree that it serves its purpose nicely.

Comment: Given that the Default for `Times` is 1, any reason not to use `a_. (_Sin | _Cos)`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just wanted to make this as straight-forward and explicit as possible, and not rely on defaults or any other particularities of the pattern-matcher, to make this code easy to generalize to other heads (if needed). You went into one extreme (using all possible special features to make it most concise), and I sort of went into the other one - use only the most basic pattern-matching and focus on general elements of parser-writing (recursion, case enumeration). I think our answers are quite complementary.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is somewhat ironic, that while your *code* itself is very concise, your answer (fully explaining it) is not. In my case, the code is more verbose, but (arguably) it explains itself to a large extent, so I could save on explanations and ended up with a shorter answer overall :).

Comment: I believe the first two lines of your code may be replaced with `parse[HoldPattern[Plus[terms__?parse]]] /; sameQ[terms] := True`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yep. This is really nice, thanks! I edited it in. I wish I thought about this myself (I do recall a number of cases when I used this sort of code).