# Given a symbolic expression how to find if starts with a minus or not?

Tags: pattern-matching, symbolic

I am using a Mathematica function which returns some error term in symbolic form. I needed a way to determine if this term starts with a minus sign or not.  *There will be only one term.*  This is to avoid having to worry about Mathematica auto arranging terms like `x-h` to become `-h+x` and hence it is not fair to ask for more than one term solution.

Here are some examples of the expressions, all in input form

```
negativeTruetests = {(-(71/12))*h^2*Derivative[4][f],
(-1)*h^2*Derivative[10][f],
(-(359/3))*h^2*Derivative[10][f], -2*h, -x*h^-2, -1/h*x }

negativeFalseTests = { h^2*Derivative[4][f] , h^2*Derivative[4][f],
33*h^2*Derivative[4][f], h^-2, 1/h}
```

I need a pattern to check if the expression starts with minus sign or not.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Does only the sign of the highest-order term of `h` count for your decision?

Comment: Only ONE term, and hence, the term, if it has a minus sign, it will have to be the first thing (looking at it, not in tree form). So, only ONE term. Hence `-h-f` will not show up. Only `(- h) * derivative(something)`  or `h*derivative` or `number*h*derivative` etc....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will use your test lists alone as reference.  If they are incomplete you will need to update the question.

When looking for a pattern for a group of expressions it is helpful to look at their `TreeForm`:

```
TreeForm /@ {negativeTruetests (*sic*), negativeFalseTests} // Column
```

[image]

[image]

You see that your True expressions always have the head `Times` with one negative leaf, be it `-1`, `-2` or a `Rational` that is negative.  Your False expressions either have head `Times` or `Power` but in the case of `Times` they do not have a negative leaf.  Therefore for these expressions you may use:

```
p = _. _?Negative;

MatchQ[#, p] & /@ negativeTruetests
MatchQ[#, p] & /@ negativeFalseTests
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True}
>
> {False, False, False, False, False}

Because of the [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) and [`OneIdentity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OneIdentity.html)<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30591/121)</sup> this pattern will also handle a negative singlet:

```
MatchQ[#, p] & /@ {-Pi, 7/22}
```

> {True, False}

---

### Format-level pattern matching

Since it was [revealed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10903852#10903852) that this question relates to formatting it may be more appropriate to perform the test in that domain.

I will use a recursive pattern as I did for [How to match expressions with a repeating pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11045/121) after converting to boxes with `ToBoxes`:

```
test = MatchQ[#, RowBox[{"-" | _?#0, __}]] & @ ToBoxes @ # &;

test /@ negativeTruetests
test /@ negativeFalseTests
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True}
>
> {False, False, False, False, False}

Another approach is to convert to a `StandardForm` string and use `StringMatchQ`, which is essentially the same as the test above because `StandardForm` uses encoded Boxes:

```
test2 = StringMatchQ[ToString[#, StandardForm], ("\!" | "\(") ... ~~ "-" ~~ __] &;

test2 /@ negativeTruetests
test2 /@ negativeFalseTests
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True}
>
> {False, False, False, False, False}

Answer (score 6):

You can do it the way a human does it: Look for the `"-"` in the string.

```
#==1&/@StringCount[ToString/@InputForm/@negativeTruetests,Alternatives["-",Repeated["("]~~"-"]]

{True,True,True}

#==1&/@StringCount[ToString/@InputForm/@negativeFalseTests,Alternatives["-",Repeated["("]~~"-"]]

{False,False,False}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are probably many creative ways to break this one horribly, but for the test cases it works:

```
(# /. Thread[Variables[#] -> 1]) < 0 & /@ negativeTruetests
```

> (* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)

```
(# /. Thread[Variables[#] -> 1]) < 0 & /@ negativeFalseTests
```

> (* {False, False, False, False, False} *)

Comment: For additional historical information, look [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10900750#10900750).

Comment: You have a bug: `expr = h^2*Derivative[4][f]- 2 h` then `(expr /. Thread[Variables[expr] -> 1]) < 0` it gives true. But it should be False !  I knew this was not as easy as it looked :) will add this to the tests

Comment: @Nasser Well, it was only designed for products... let´s see

Comment: I think it is ok. Adding terms is not fair. Since Mathematica will rearrange terms on its own. So `x-h` might end up as `-h+x`. So let just leave it at one term for now. I did not mean for this to become too hard.

Answer (score 5):

All of your examples are of the form `Times[...]`, which case you can do this (on the original examples):

```
MemberQ[#, _?Negative] & /@ Flatten[{negativeFalseTests, negativeTruetests}]
(* {False, False, False, True, True, True} *)
```

or this

```
expr /. {Times[c_?NumericQ, ___] :> c < 0, _Times :> False}
```

but not this

```
MemberQ[#, _?Negative] & /@ {h^-2}
(* {True} *)
```

---

**Edit**

Here's a modification of the second method that works on powers, now with the updated examples:

```
# /. {Times[c_?NumericQ, ___] :> c < 0, _ :> False} & /@ 
   Flatten[{negativeFalseTests, negativeTruetests}]
(* {False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Yes, the last case, `h^-2` should NOT be negative. THere is only ONE term, all symbolic, but can start with a minus sign or not. Hence $h^{-2}$ should not be valid for saying it starts with minus sign. For example, `MemberQ[#, _?Negative] & /@ {1/h}` return TRUE, which is not right.

Comment: @Nasser I know that. I was asking whether that use-case is to be handled or not.  I take it might arise and you would like a solution that includes it.

Comment: Sure. I know you knew that and were just checking on requirements. Will add it to the question to be more clear. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about looking at the displayed boxes? Specifically, look for the first `RowBox` containing a string as its first element (as opposed to another box), and check to see if that string is a minus sign:

```
SetAttributes[isMinus, {HoldFirst}];
isMinus[expr_] := Cases[MakeBoxes[expr], RowBox[{s_String, ___}] :> s, {0, -1}, 1] == {"-"}

isMinus /@ negativeTruetests
(* {True, True, True} *)

isMinus /@ negativeFalseTests
(* {False, False, False} *)
```

`isMinus` doesn't evaluate its argument, so for example:

```
isMinus[h^2*Derivative[4][f] - 2 h]
(* False *)
```

The first term has no minus sign so the result is false. However, if *Mathematica* is allowed to evalute the argument it will rearrange the expression to put `-2h` at the beginning, so:

```
isMinus[Evaluate[h^2*Derivative[4][f] - 2 h]]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

This function

```
 checkMinus[expr_] := 
 Select[expr /. Head[expr] -> List, # < 0 &] // Length
```

applied to your terms returns 1, if there is a minus in the expression with the structure you indicated, and 0 in the opposite case.

```
checkMinus[-((h^12 m'[0])/24)]

(* 1  *)

checkMinus[(h^4 m'[0])/12]

(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the undocumented, internal function `` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ `` for this purpose (see this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103004/45431)):

```
Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ /@ negativeTruetests
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True}

```
Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ /@ negativeFalseTests
```

> {False, False, False, False, False}

Answer (score 2):

```
  dummy = (1.0/1.0);
  Negative[Extract[dummy*(#), 1]] & /@ negativeTruetests
   (* {True, True, True} *)

  Negative[Extract[dummy*(#), 1]] & /@ negativeFalseTests
   {False, False, False}
```

Comment: THat does not work?  `Negative[Extract[ h^2*Derivative[4][f], 1]]` gives `Negative[h^2]`  It has to work even if there is no number at the start of the expression. I'll add that as an example also.

Comment: Multiplying by that dummy seems to work.I know its ugly but it works right:).

Comment: Nope. Expression returned does not have a dummy. Have to use the expressions as shown. Can't modify them. These are returned from a function.

Comment: Why cant you do like Negative[Extract[dummy*(Last@FDFormula[]), 1]]

Comment: I tried you solution like this: `Negative[Extract[dummy*negativeFalseTests, 1]]` and I get this: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SEMWU.png)

Comment: @Nasser How about now.I have edited my answer