# List manipulation - various

Tags: list-manipulation, series-expansion

## Update

OK, Please forgive the messiness of this, but I am working with something like:

```
d = (q = 8;
f = (lop = 
  Transpose[{Flatten[
     Reverse[Table[
        Gamma[y], {y, 1, q + 1}]] /. {ComplexInfinity -> 0}], 
    Flatten[Table[Binomial[n, k], {n, q, q}, {k, 0, n}]], 
    Flatten[Table[x^n, {n, 0, q}]]}];
 {#1*#2*#3} & @@@ lop);
Flatten[f];
Total[f]);
d
```

which gives:

```
{40320 + 40320 x + 20160 x^2 + 6720 x^3 + 1680 x^4 + 336 x^5 + 56 x^6 + 8 x^7 + x^8}
```

I am then comparing the roots with another series, eg:

```
Normal[Series[E^x, {x, 0, 8}]]
```

which, in this case are the same.

However, I have lots of different series & was wondering if I could manipulate them as stated below.

*(NB - I realise there is no 'ComplexInfinity' output in the above example, but have left it in to demonstrate that I have tried several replace techniques for the subsequent questions.)*

## Original question

I have several questions on list manipulation & at the risk of asking the same question multiple times, I have compiled them into the following single question:

(a) Changing alternate (or some other pattern) signs / operators:

From this:

```
1 + x + (x^2)/2! +  (x^3)/3! + (x^4)/4! +  (x^5)/5! ...
```

I would like to do get this:

```
1 - x + (x^2)/2! -  (x^3)/3! + (x^4)/4! -  (x^5)/5! ...
```

(b) Multiplying alternate (or some other pattern) elements by a given value (eg - I):

From this:

```
1 + x + (x^2)/2! +  (x^3)/3! + (x^4)/4! +  (x^5)/5! ...
```

I would like to do get this:

```
1 - I x + (x^2)/2! -  I(x^3)/3! + (x^4)/4! -  I(x^5)/5! ...
```

(c) Convert all Imaginary values in a list to real values (or vice versa), noting that there may be no pattern in the distribution here:

From this:

```
1 + I x + (x^2)/2! +  (x^3)/3! + I(x^4)/4! +  I(x^5)/5! ...
```

I would like to do get this:

```
1 + x + (x^2)/2! +  (x^3)/3! + (x^4)/4! +  (x^5)/5! ...
```

or this:

```
I + I x + I(x^2)/2! +  I(x^3)/3! + I (x^4)/4! +  I(x^5)/5! ...
```

I have tried various select & replace methods, but have had no luck so far.

Comment: Maybe related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30907/131

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can begin by wrapping your expression in `Hold` or `HoldForm` then using `ReleaseHold` when you want to `Evaluate` them. For your first example:

```
expr = HoldForm[1 + x + (x^2)/2! + (x^3)/3! + (x^4)/4! + (x^5)/5!]
```

Now you can do:

```
Replace[expr /. {Times[c : Power[x, n_?OddQ], d_] :> Times[-1, c, d]}, x -> - x, 2]
```

To get:

```
1 - x + x^2/2! - x^3/3! + x^4/4! - x^5/5!
```

For the next one:

```
Replace[expr /. {Times[c : Power[x, n_?OddQ], d_] :> Times[-I, c, d]}, x -> - I x, 2]
```

Which gives:

```
1 - I x + x^2/2! - (I x^3)/3! + x^4/4! - (I x^5)/5!
```

For the third:

```
expr2 = 1 + I x + (x^2)/2! + (x^3)/3! + I (x^4)/4! + I (x^5)/5!;
```

To change the imaginary numbers do:

```
expr2 /. Complex[0, c_] :> c
```

To change negatives to positives in e.g.

```
expr3 = -1 - x + (x^2)/2! - (x^3)/3! + (x^4)/4! - (x^5)/5!
```

Simply do:

```
expr3 /. {Times[-1, c_] :> Times[1, c], Rational[-1, d_] :> Rational[1, d], n_?Negative :> -1 n}
```

To get:

```
1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24 + x^5/120
```

Comment: @ RunnyKine,Great, this works well for alternating series, but I was wondering if I could select all negative values & change them, or all imaginary values, etc.

Comment: @ RunnyKine, Many thanks. - Is it possible to change the negative values to positive? (Would I use an 'If' statement?)

Comment: @martin, yes you can change negatives to positives. I'll add that now.

Comment: @ RunnyKine, Many thanks :-)

Comment: @martin. Glad I could help.

Comment: @ RunnyKine, sorry - slight glitch with neg -> pos - have created new post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35514/change-all-values-of-a-series-to-positive-values for this so as not to over-complicate things here too much. - Thanks for your patience on this btw!