# Change all values of a series to positive values

Tags: list-manipulation, series-expansion

I would like to change all values of a series to positive values.

I refer to my previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/list-manipulation-various), answered in the most part, very elegantly by RunnyKine. However, there remains a slight glitch that I can't seem to overcome:

```
expr1 = x + (2 x^2)/y - (3 x^3)/y^2;
expr1 /. {Times[-1, c_] :> Times[1, c], Rational[-1, d_] :> 
Rational[1, d], n_?Negative :> -1 n}
```

gives:

```
x + 2 x^2 y + 3 x^3 y^2
```

I can't seem to fathom where the missing '/' has gone from between the x & y values.

Comment: Although there are already answers for your specific problem here, the question "How to change all values of a series to positive values" cannot be answered in general. Even if you assume that all your variables are positive, one can easily construct examples where all approaches fail. A simple pattern match will only help you in very simple situations. Consider the following example: `exp = x + (2 x^2)/y - (3 x^3)/y^2 + (- Sin[z]^2 - Cos[z]^2)/(-z)` and try `FullSimplify /@ exp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr1 = x + (2 x^2)/y - (3 x^3)/y^2;
```

Now:

```
expr1 /. {Times[n_?Negative, c_] :> Times[-1 n, c], Rational[-1, d_] :> Rational[1, d]}
```

Gives:

```
x + (3 x^3)/y^2 + (2 x^2)/y
```

**UPDATE**

If there are standalone numbers in the series as in e.g.

```
expr2 = -2 + x + (2 x^2)/y - (3 x^3)/y^2;
```

Then the following more general solution should be used:

```
Replace[expr2 /. {Times[n_?Negative, c_] :> Times[-1 n, c], 
                         Rational[-1, d_] :> Rational[1, d]}, n_?Negative :> -1 n, {1}]
```

Which gives:

```
2 + x + (3 x^3)/y^2 + (2 x^2)/y
```

Comment: @ RunnyKine, Apologies & many thanks :-)

Comment: @martin. No worries, hope this helped.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way, if the `y`s all appear in the denominator.  We convert the expression to a polynomial with `y -> 1/u` and use some of the polynomial functions.

```
expr1 = x + (2 x^2)/y - (3 x^3)/y^2;
FromCoefficientRules[
 MapAt[Abs, CoefficientRules[expr1 /. y -> 1/u, {x, u}], {All, {-1}}],
 {x, 1/y}]

(* x + (3 x^3)/y^2 + (2 x^2)/y *)
```

Another example:

```
Normal@Series[-2 Exp[-x^2/y], {x, 0, 7}]
(* -2 + x^6/(3 y^3) - x^4/y^2 + (2 x^2)/y *)

FromCoefficientRules[
 MapAt[Abs,
       CoefficientRules[Normal@Series[-2 Exp[-x^2/y], {x, 0, 7}] /. y -> 1/u, {x, u}],
       {All, -1}],
 {x, 1/y}]

(* 2 + x^6/(3 y^3) + x^4/y^2 + (2 x^2)/y *)
```

---

To answer the implicit question about how to figure out what went wrong with the pattern replacement (the case of the disappearing `/`), it is a good idea to start by examining the `FullForm` of the expression.

```
FullForm[expr1]
(* Plus[x, Times[-3, Power[x, 3], Power[y, -2]], Times[2, Power[x, 2], Power[y, -1]]] *)
```

And if you have trouble seeing the problem, you can use some of the other pattern-matching functions to test your patterns.  Here `Cases` can be helpful.

```
Cases[expr1, n_?Negative, Infinity]
(* {-3, -2, -1} *)
```

Now look where those negative numbers come from.  One is a coefficient; the others are exponents from powers of `y`.  All are multiplied by `-1` by your replacement, which converts the negative powers of `y` to positive powers, in effect removing the `/` from each.