# How to modify the label code that appears on the image so that+- does not appear together?

Tags: plotting

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[A Sin[\[Omega] x + \[Phi]] + B, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "f(x)=" <> ToString[A] <> "sin(" <> ToString[\[Omega]] <> "x+" <> 
    ToString[\[Phi]] <> ")+" <> ToString[B], PlotRange -> {-6, 6}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> 700, 
  Ticks -> {Table[i, {i, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi], \[Pi]/4}], 
    Table[t, {t, -5, 5, 0.5}]}], {{A, 1}, -5, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Omega], 1}, -3, 8, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Phi], 0}, -\[Pi], 2 \[Pi], 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{B, 0}, -1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

How to modify the following label code so that when the value of [Phi] is negative, only a - sign is used to connect it in the middle, instead of continuously appearing in the label+-

```
PlotLabel -> 
   "f(x)=" <> ToString[A] <> "sin(" <> ToString[\[Omega]] <> "x+" <> 
    ToString[\[Phi]] <> ")+" <> ToString[B]
```

[image]

Comment: always use `TrackedSymbols` in Manipulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another option

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{e, p},
  p = _. _?Negative; 
  e = "f(x)=" <> ToString[A] <> " sin(" <> ToString[ω] <> 
    " x " <> If[MatchQ[ϕ, p], "", "+"] <> ToString[ϕ] <> 
    ")" <> If[MatchQ[B, p], "", "+"] <> ToString[B];
  p = Plot[A Sin[ω x + ϕ] + B, {x, -10, 10},
    PlotLabel -> e,
    PlotRange -> {-6, 6}, Axes -> True,
    AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
    AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> 700,
    Ticks -> {Table[i, {i, -4 π, 4 π, π/4}], 
      Table[t, {t, -5, 5, 0.5}]}
    ];
  p
  ],
 {{A, 1}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ω, 1}, -3, 8, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ϕ, 0}, -π, 2 π, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{B, 0}, -1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {A, ω, ϕ, B}]
```

[image]

Reference [Given a symbolic expression how to find if starts with a minus or not?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30907/given-a-symbolic-expression-how-to-find-if-starts-with-a-minus-or-not)

Answer (score 3):

Add a variable (I am using `plotLabel`) with `ControlType -> None`.

Use a `Which` statement to remove the + sign when `\[Phi]`is negative. (I also removed it entirely when `\[Phi]` was 0).

```
Manipulate[
 plotLabel = Which[
   \[Phi] < 0,
   "f(x)=" <> ToString[A] <> "sin(" <> ToString[\[Omega]] <> "x" <> 
    ToString[\[Phi]] <> ")+" <> ToString[B],
   Or[\[Phi] == 0.0, \[Phi] == 0],
   "f(x)=" <> ToString[A] <> "sin(" <> ToString[\[Omega]] <> "x)+" <> 
    ToString[B],
   True,
   "f(x)=" <> ToString[A] <> "sin(" <> ToString[\[Omega]] <> "x+" <> 
    ToString[\[Phi]] <> ")+" <> ToString[B]
   ];
 
 Plot[A Sin[\[Omega] x + \[Phi]] + B, {x, -10, 10},
  PlotLabel -> plotLabel,
  PlotRange -> {-6, 6}, Axes -> True,
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
  AxesLabel -> {x, y},
  ImageSize -> 700, Ticks -> {
    Table[i, {i, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi], \[Pi]/4}],
    Table[t, {t, -5, 5, 0.5}]
    }
  ],
 {{A, 1}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Omega], 1}, -3, 8, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Phi], 0}, -\[Pi], 2 \[Pi], 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{B, 0}, -1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {plotLabel, ControlType -> None}
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`StringForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 f[x_] = A Sin[ω x + ϕ] + B;
 Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10},
  PlotLabel -> StringForm["`` = ``", HoldForm@f[x], f[x]],
  PlotRange -> {-6, 6},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
  AxesLabel -> {x, y},
  ImageSize -> 700,
  Ticks -> {Range[-4 π, 4 π, π/4], Range[-5, 5, 0.5]}],
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{A, 1}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{B, 0}, -1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{ω, 1}, -3, 8, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{ϕ, 0}, -π, 2 π, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}}],
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {A, ω, ϕ, B}]
```

[image]