# Extracting argument sequences from function expressions

Tags: pattern-matching

Why is it that

```
fun[x, y] /. fun[z__] :> z
```

leads to

> ```
> Sequence[x,y]
> ```

but

```
Dot[x, y] /. Dot[z__] :> z
```

gives

> ```
> Dot[x,y]
> ```

I want it to be

> ```
> Sequence[x,y]
> ```

Makes no sense.  How do I make it work like I think it should?

Comment: I thought it was related to the attribute `OneIdentity` (or `Flat`) of `Dot` but I can't reproduce the behaviour using a custom head that has these attributes set.

Comment: Yeah,  I thought it was that too.  But it turned out not to be.

Comment: Related: [Pattern matching on Orderless functions inside Hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30152/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `Dot[z__]` is evaluated to `z__`

The solution:

```
 Dot[x, y] /. HoldPattern[Dot[z__]] :> z
```

> Sequence[x, y]

Comment: Alternatives: `Dot[x, y] /. Verbatim[Dot][z__] :> z` and `Dot[x, y] /. (p : Dot)[z__] :> z`

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't explain the behavior you notice (andre's answer does) and all the right methods have been covered here (See Mr.Wizard's alternatives), I found a nice work-around that will work with any `Head` (replace `Dot` with your `Head` of choice). Here it is:

```
Dot[x, y] /. z_Dot :> Sequence @@ z

(* Sequence[x, y] *)
```

Comment: This is a good alternative.  Be aware that there is an evaluation difference that affects held expressions, e.g.:  `Hold[{Dot[x, y]}] /. z_Dot :> q[Sequence @@ z]` (or more simply `z_Dot :> q @@ z`) versus `Hold[{Dot[x, y]}] /. Verbatim[Dot][z__] :> q[z]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks, that's an interesting example and I guess one can always use Trott-Strzebonski to save the day `Hold[{Dot[x, y]}] /. z_Dot :> With[{s = q[Sequence @@ z]}, s /; True]`

Comment: That is yet another evaluation sequence because you are inducing evaluation where there otherwise would be none.  As a counterexample consider: `Hold[{Dot[1, 2]}] /. Verbatim[Dot][z__] :> +z`.  I think you will find this hard to do in a single step using `z_Dot :> . . .`; in fact if you can I want to know about it because I can't think of a solution.