# How to replace the first occurence in an expression instead of replacing all?

Tags: functions, replacement, functional-style

Is there a function that replaces the first occurence of the expression instead of replacing all? For example, if I have `HoldForm[x + 2 + 4 + x] /. x -> 4`, is there a way to return `4 + 2 + 4 + x`?

Comment: $f_x^x$ Which one is the first `x` ?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I guess if you hit Ctrl+Shift+E, and the first occurence of x is what I meant

Comment: What I mean is that the order of the symbols in a general math expression doesn't mean anything "in general". Perhaps if you restrict the domain of the expressions ...

Comment: fun `ClearAll[r]; r[4] := (r[4] = x; 4); HoldForm[x + 2 + 4 + x] /. x :> RuleCondition@r[4]` and for less fun take a look at `Position` 4th arg + `ReplacePart`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another way:

```
hf = HoldForm[x + 2 + 4 + x]
i = 0
hf /. (x :> 4 /; i++ == 0)
```

> 4 + 2 + 4 + x

Answer (score 16):

Well here's a way. Find the position of the first occurrence of `x`:

```
expr = HoldForm[x + 2 + 4 + x];

pos = Position[expr, x, -1, 1];
```

Then:

```
ReplacePart[expr, pos -> 4]
```

> 4 + 2 + 4 + x

Comment: +1 With version 10, we can use `FirstPosition`, e.g. `HoldForm[x + 2 + 4 + x] // ReplacePart[#, FirstPosition[#, x] -> 4] &`.

Comment: @WReach I was just updating the answer with that optimization.  I considered using `FirstPosition` but it doesn't seem to bring much benefit here (a bit of clarity I guess) so I used the general equivalent.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks for the update, certainly cleaner :)

Comment: @WReach, good point, I forgot about `FirstPosition`

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

For order preserving as Jens says, I changed `Attributes`

```
ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless]

HoldForm[7 + x + 2 + 4 + x + 5] /. f___ + x + l___ :> f + 4 + l
```

> 7 + 4 + 2 + 4 + x + 5

And you can revert by `SetAttributes[Plus, Orderless]`

---

**Origin**

How about this

```
HoldForm[x + 2 + 4 + x] /. x + a___ -> 4 + a
```

> 4 + 2 + 4 + x

Comment: It won't work with this example: `HoldForm[7 + x + 2 + 4 + x] /. x + a___ -> 4 + a` because the order isn't preserved.

Comment: @Jens : I got it, and I changed attributes.

Comment: Yes, that works. But now you'd have to do the same if it were `Times` instead of `Plus`... anyway, you put your finger exactly on the reason why the original didn't work, and changing the attributes is certainly a way to make it work.

Comment: Related: [(30152)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30152)

Comment: @Jens : I see. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = HoldForm[x + 2 + 4 + x];
expr[[##& @@ FirstPosition[expr, x]]] = 4; expr
```

> 4 + 2 + 4 + x