# Pattern does not match with Orderless head

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, hold, attributes

Why does the following pattern matching not succeed?

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f,Orderless];
HoldForm[f[a,d[],b,c]]/.HoldPattern[f[a,d[],b,z_]]:>{z}
(* f[a,d[],b,c] *)
```

I expected that because `f` is `Orderless`, the pattern matcher should try all possible orders of arguments and find a match.

If the expression is not held, I find:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f,Orderless];
f[a,d[],b,c]/.HoldPattern[f[a,d[],b,z_]]:>{z}
(* {c} *)
```

I.e. the desired result.
I know that because `f` is `Orderless` and the expression is evaluated, the arguments are sorted into canonical order `a, b, c, d[]`.
It would appear in this case that the pattern matcher really does try all possible orders of arguments to find a match.

Why doesn't it work in the first example?

EDIT:

Here are some further examples:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, Orderless];

Hold[f[a, b, c, d[]]] /. HoldPattern[f[a, b, c, z_]] :> {"Matched", {z}}
(* Hold[{"Matched", {d[]}}] *)

Hold[f[a, b, c[], d]] /. HoldPattern[f[a, b, c[], z_]] :> {"Matched", {z}}
(* Hold[{"Matched", {d}}] *)

Hold[f[a, b[], c, d]] /. HoldPattern[f[a, b[], c, z_]] :> {"Matched", {z}}
(* Hold[f[a, b[], c, d]] *)

Hold[f[a[], b, c, d]] /. HoldPattern[f[a[], b, c, z_]] :> {"Matched", {z}}
(* Hold[f[a[], b, c, d]] *)
```

This seems very inconsistent to me; how can I understand what is happening here?

EDIT:

An illuminating example:

```
Hold[f[a, c, b[], d]] /. HoldPattern[f[a, b[], c, z_]] :> {"Matched", {z}}
(* Hold[{"Matched", {d}}] *)
```

The `Trace` shows no argument reordering, but it appears that the pattern matcher must actually be reordering the pattern to (the canonical order) `f[a, c, b[], z_]` because `f` is `Orderless`, even though `HoldPattern` should prevent "regular" evaluation.

What remains confusing is what exactly is meant by "In matching patterns with Orderless functions, all possible orders of arguments are tried." in the documentation. On face value, the four examples shown above contradict this.

Comment: I am confused. `HoldForm[f[a, d[], c]] /. HoldPattern[f[a, d[], c_]] :> {c}` outputs `{c}`, and if you stop `f` from being `Orderless` then the we likewise get `HoldForm[f[a, d[], b, c]] /. HoldPattern[f[a, d[], b, c_]] :> {c}` outputting `{c}`. It seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: Indeed, quite confusing!

Comment: But your `Verbatim` trick works! `HoldForm[f[a, d[], b, c]] /. Verbatim[f][a, d[], b, z_] :> {z}` yields `{c}`. Although if you lose the `HoldForm`, it doesn't work...

Comment: `Verbatim` works because `f` is no longer treated as a head for pattern matching purposes, and so its `Orderless` attribute has no effect. But why that attribute prevents the match in the first place is unclear :/

Comment: And `Verbatim` _doesn't_ work without the `HoldForm` on the expression, because the arguments of the expression will be sorted into canonical form but those of the pattern will not be able to shuffle, so there is no way for the pattern to match.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am betting that this is almost certainly an optimization short-cut.  If `Orderless` had to try *every* ordering it would be *extremely* slow when there are a moderate number of arguments, but it is not.

Consider for example:

```
f @@@ Hold @@ {RandomSample[Range@12]}
Hold @@ {f @@ Range@12 /. {7 -> _}}
MatchQ[%%, %]
```

> ```
> Hold[f[2, 6, 11, 7, 12, 10, 4, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]]
>
> Hold[f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, _]]
>
> False
> ```

This test is surely not performing 479,001,600 comparisons, one for each permutation.  Instead I suppose that pattern matching *assumes* that arguments of `Orderless` heads will first be placed in order and applies logic accordingly.

Since the first two of your "further examples" match I also suppose that this is because the sorted order of arguments on the RHS matches the verbatim order on the left; perhaps this case is tried first.

Comment: Best hypothesis so far... I suppose that the best practice would be to not `Hold` such patterns or simply deactivate `Orderless` heads during pattern matching?

Answer (score 6):

The following is an expansion of the [explanation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94569/280) given by Mr.Wizard.

---

The pattern-matcher works on the base of the assumption that `Orderless` attribute is already applied and the arguments of the `Orderless` function are already sorted in the canonical order:

```
ClearAll[o]
SetAttributes[o, Orderless]
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, x, a]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]] (* unsorted arguments: {x, a} is NOT ordered *)
MatchQ[Hold[Evaluate@o[y, x, a]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]] (* Orderless attribute is applied *)
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```

Instead of `Hold` we can use `Unevaluated` with the same effect:

```
MatchQ[Unevaluated[o[y, x, a]], o[_, x, a]] (* {x, a} is NOT ordered *)
MatchQ[Unevaluated[o[y, a, x]], o[_, x, a]] (* {a, x} IS ordered *)
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```

`Hold` and `Unevaluated` prevent applying the `Orderless` attribute to the arguments of the `Orderless` function. They only affect the *evaluation* of the expression, and do not affect the pattern-matcher.

The pattern-matcher does not reorder the arguments of the `Orderless` function but takes the whole expression verbatim. It *assumes* that the arguments are already sorted as it happens by default for *evaluated* function with `Orderless` attribute. At the same time the pattern-matcher *does sort* the arguments of the pattern (with the exception of `Blank`s) regardless of whether the pattern is evaluated or not. Then it compares the *sorted* pattern with the expression putting `Blank`(s) in each position possible in the pattern.

In the light of this the Documentation [statement](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html)

> In matching patterns with `Orderless` functions, all possible orders of
>   arguments are tried.

is misleading: actually only all possible *positions* of the `Blank`s in the pattern are tried but other arguments *in the pattern* are preliminarily sorted in the fixed canonical order. This is evident from the following:

```
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, a, x]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]] (* {a, x} IS ordered *)
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, x, a]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]] (* {x, a} is NOT ordered  *)
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, a, x]], Hold[o[x, _, a]]] (* {a, x} IS ordered *)
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, a, x]], Hold[o[x, a, _]]] (* {a, x} IS ordered *)
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
>
> True
>
> True
> ```

In short, `Hold` prevents applying `Orderless` attribute in the sense that it prevents sorting of the arguments in the canonical order, but it does not prevent action of this attribute in the pattern (i.e. all possible positions of the `Blank`s are indeed tried).

Comment: This does not seem exactly correct.  With g Orderless, I find `MatchQ[Hold[g[y, a, x]], Hold[g[a, x, _]]] -> True` but `MatchQ[Hold[g[y, x, a]], Hold[g[x, a, _]]] -> False`.  What am I missing?

Comment: @JohnMcGee Your second example is essentially identical to mine `MatchQ[Hold[o[y, x, a]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]]`. In the both cases the output is `False` because the sequence `x, a` in the expression we test against pattern is not in the canonical order. It immediately matches if we place arguments in the canonical order: `MatchQ[Hold[g[y, a, x]], Hold[g[x, a, _]]]` for your example and `MatchQ[Hold[o[y, a, x]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]]` for mine (both give `True`). This also explains your first example.

Comment: It would be useful to more explicitly say that arguments of the expression are not reordered while those in the pattern are sorted, with the exception of blanks, put in each possible position.  For a complete picture one can run `Table[Print[{expr, patt} -> MatchQ[expr, patt]], {expr, Map[Hold[#] /. oo -> o &, Permutations[oo[a, x, y]]]}, {patt, Map[Hold[#] /. oo -> o &, Permutations[oo[a, x, _]]]}]` and see that the order of the pattern `patt` does not matter.  Matching happens exactly if `a` and `x` appear in the canonical order in the expression.