# Why does MatchQ[Hold[c + b + a], Hold[x_ + b + a]] return False?

Tags: pattern-matching, hold

Can anyone explain why the following pattern matches:

```
[In1]:MatchQ[Hold[a + c + b], Hold[x_ + b + a]]
[Out1]:True
```

But this one fails:

```
[In1]:MatchQ[Hold[c + b + a], Hold[x_ + b + a]]
[Out1]:False
```

It seems that the pattern matcher tries all permutations even if the Plus expression is held (case 1), so why does it fail for case 2?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94432/pattern-does-not-match-with-orderless-head)

Comment: This is an interesting question that seems not to have a simple answer. Maybe you will ask: support@wolfram.com and tell us what they replied.